# How to do Frontend Progressive Loading with Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, performance, frontend

Like trello(http://trello.com), my site need to render a lot of "cards". And each "card" contain some "items".

I did that using standard Django template. To render, I basically run a double loop. The problems occur when I have more cards to render and the page loading becomes really slow.

I read about progressive loading here: http://blog.fogcreek.com/we-spent-a-week-making-trello-boards-load-extremely-fast-heres-how-we-did-it/

So how could I achieve something similar in my case as well? Should I just render the container in the django template and the rest using Javascript? I would like to know what's the best strategy to do this.

**EDIT**
I found this http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/, which is really helpful

Comment: I would say it depends where most of your UI-controller code lives. If your UI will have to do a lot of "live" updates with drag/drop, inline edit etc. then it's better to build the UI in JavaScript (Backbone or something like that) and use e.g. http://www.django-rest-framework.org for persistance.

Comment: @toabi Thanks for the comment. That's how trello did it as well.http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/